# How many contact-hours should I have with students? (Secondary Ed.)

Tags: statistics, scheduling, time-management

I'm interested in discovering how many hours of contact math educators have with their students each week. I've done some research and gotten some averages by country, but I can't find enough data (distributions) to determine if my classroom time is significantly below average.

I realize than many countries (and states in the US) have determined a minimum number of annual hours of "instruction"; however, this often includes lunch breaks, study halls, and other time that is not specifically used for instruction.

What is an overview of general guidelines as to how many contact hours I should have with my students? How many hours do you have and how does it work?

Comment: This sounds more like a poll than an SE-type question to me. Perhaps something in this direction would work better: "Can you suggest some general guidelines as to how many contact hours I should have with my students? How many hours do you have and how does it work?"

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I appreciate your comment, but I specifically asked if survey questions were on-topic in meta and was told (in a moderator comment) that they are.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/505/are-survey-questions-on-topic I will edit the question to reflect your feedback though, thank you

Comment: Why do you think this should have any form of correct answer? Surely the number of contact hours needs to be aligned to what achievement is expected as a result of those hours. At 16 maths was one of the 10 subjects I was studying, whereas by 17 it could have made up 2/3 of my school time. Different places have different numbers of weeks. Some ideas could be taught inside other subjects.

Comment: @JessicaB Its a subjective survey question. I would expect answers to say "I do ______ and it works because ________" or "the _______ organization recommends __________ because of this data __________"